# how to sum frequency respectively by numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The result I want:

```
List       Result List

1          1
1          2
2          1
2          2
2          3
3          1
4          1
```

Now I use for loop, how can I use numpy way to come true it?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html

Comment: You got the right answer here : -)

Comment: Thanks! I learn a new function cumcount! Thanks both of you